# Reorient Matplotlib polar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot, polar-coordinates

I would like to produce a polar scatterplot in matplotlib. The plot I have from using `ax1 = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)` looks fine, but I need to deviate from the usual polar graph orientation.

1. I need 0 degrees to point straight up (rotation).
2. I need 90 degrees to point right (mirror image).

(How) Can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need `ax.set_theta_zero_location` and `ax.set_theta_direction`.
For details, see [the doc](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/api/projections_api.html)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


r = range(360)
angles = [i * np.pi / 180 for i in r]

f = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(polar=True)
plt.polar(angles, r)

ax.set_xticks(angles[::10])
ax.set_theta_zero_location("N")
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)

plt.show()
```